# move_upload_file uploading old file?

Tags: php, file

I'm working on an "Edit post" page which allows users to upload a picture to replace their old picture (displayed at the bottom of the post). Here's the code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['pic']['name']!=NULL) {

            $target_file1 = $dir . $postid . "." . $imageFileType1;
            $target_png1 = $dir . $postid . ".png";
            $target_jpg1 = $dir . $postid . ".jpg";
            $target_jpeg1 = $dir . $postid . ".jpeg";

            if (file_exists($target_png1)) {
                unlink($target_png1);
            }
            if (file_exists($target_jpg1)) {
                unlink($target_jpg1);
            }
            if (file_exists($target_jpeg1)) {
                unlink($target_jpeg1);
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file1);
        }
```

Through doing testing, I know that it works fine as long as the new picture is a different extension from the original. But if it's the same extension it deletes the old one and the move_uploaded_file reuploads the old one.

I know this because I commented out the "move_uploaded_files" and it successfully deleted the old file.

Any clues why it would be reuploading the old file instead of the uploaded one?

Comment: Make sure that you are clearing your cache, if the file extension is not changing your browser may have an old copy of the original image saved and is serving that to the browser. try Ctrl+F5

Comment: it wouldn't. php will auto-delete any unhandled upload files, so there's no way an "old" file could be magically left at the `['tmp_name']` location. did you check if the browser was force-reloaded? the old image may be getting cached.

Comment: Just a warning... Continually flush your browser's cache when working on something like this. You can spend days working on a problem that turns out to be that your local browser cached an old image and didn't fetch a new one.

Comment: Apart from the browser's cache, also make sure you always enable development mode (or something similar) when you use a CDN like CloudFlare.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to overwrite files? Maybe add `if (file_exists($target_file1)) {
                unlink($target_file1);
   }`as well

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I thought about cache, except I'm actually looking at the file manager on my host server so I figured that wouldn't be an issue. However, it still might be when I "view" the file. I'll check.

Comment: Okay, you are correct it was the cache issue. I didn't think about the browser opening to show the picture from the file manager. D'oh!